# Steam error: failed to load drivers swrast

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam

Updated the question as there is no solution till now and now i am using 17.04

```
athul@black-box:~/Downloads$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1490228413)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

athul@black-box:~/Downloads$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib32/nvidia-340/:/usr/lib/nvidia-340/" steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1490228413)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

**Second Method used to work for a while though** early before update.

Comment: What *exactly* did you try and what's the output of `steam` now?

Comment: @David Foerster The output is same as i described here.I removed libstdc++ and libgcc_s and all other files as mentioned in solution below.I removed and installed steam multiple times and tried various solution available online.Only after that i am posting it here.  And i am getting this error.I messed with mesa too while trying to solve it. I was being shown  no video mode activated message. After reinstalling latest nvidia i resolved it. Now i have not much idea how deleting this files will help also. A solution with detail will be of great help.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please try [this](/a/768841/175814)?

Comment: [David Foerster](http://askubuntu.com/users/175814/david-foerster) i tried those.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

This is because steam ships and uses older libraries.

Remove `libstdc++`

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed/libstdc++6-4.6-pic_4.6.3-1ubuntu5+srt4_amd64 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed/libstdc++6-4.6-pic_4.6.3-1ubuntu5+srt4_amd64.md5 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed/libstdc++6_4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04+steamrt2+srt1_amd64 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed/libstdc++6_4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04+steamrt2+srt1_amd64.md5 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++_pic.a && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++_pic.map && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6-4.6-pic && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/installed/libstdc++6-4.6-pic_4.6.3-1ubuntu5+srt4_i386 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/installed/libstdc++6-4.6-pic_4.6.3-1ubuntu5+srt4_i386.md5 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/installed/libstdc++6_4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04+steamrt2+srt1_i386 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/installed/libstdc++6_4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04+steamrt2+srt1_i386.md5 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++_pic.a && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++_pic.map && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6-4.6-pic && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6
```

Remove `libgcc_s`

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 && rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

After doing this, try to launch Steam again. It should be able to run properly now.

---

### Note

There may be more of these files you have to remove, so try these commands first, then run `updatedb` command try and locate any of these librarires again. (If you get command not found when running `updatedb` you need to install the `mlocate` package)

---

#### References

[Steam won't open, libGL errors](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1504046#p1504046)